# Check in array if theres a new value or deleted value from another array

Tags: php

i have here 2 arrays. what I need is to compare these to and find what is added and deleted on the array $a

```
$a = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
$b = array("1", "3", "4", "5", "6");

// output:
$deleted = array("2");
$added = array("5", "6");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `array_diff()`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

```
$a = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
$b = array("1", "3", "4", "5", "6");

$deleted = array_diff($a, $b);
$added = array_diff($b, $a);

print_r($deleted);
print_r($added);
```